# Why does MongoDB increase _id by one when inserting with custom id value

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I am having some weird issue when inserting a new document with a custom _id value. If i insert a document with a custom _id of 102071663223038**3** it gets saved in the database as 102071663223038**4**. For some reason it is incremented by 1.

what may cause this?

My query is :

```
exports.register = function(req, res){
console.log('ATTEMPT to register a user with id: ' + req.body.userInfo.id);  
// prints 1020716632230383 !!!

var query = {'_id': req.body.userInfo.id};

var update = {
    '_id': req.body.userInfo.id ,  
    'name': req.body.userInfo.name 
};

var options = {
    upsert: true,   
    setDefaultsOnInsert : true
};

User.findOneAndUpdate(query, update, options).exec(function(err ,doc){
    if(!err){
        console.log('REGISTERED!: ' , doc);
        res.status(200).json({'success': true, 'doc': doc});
    }else{
        console.log(err);
        res.status(200).json({'success': false});
    }

});
};
```

In my Schema the _id is defined to be a number.

```
_id: {type:Number}
```

Answer (score 0):

it is because "setDefaultsOnInsert : true" . when you use this option you can't update "_id" field. it is setting by mongoose.
if you want have a custom "_id" be sure "setDefaultsOnInsert" option is "false".
it is one of problems in mongoose .